# How can I put two pagebreaks after a chapter title?

Tags: chapters, blank-page

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} ‎
\begin{document} ‎‎
‎\chapter{Chapter One}‎
‎\newpage‎‎
‎\newpage‎‎‎
\lipsum[1-2]
‎\end{document}‎
```

How can I make the chapter start after a blank page so that the back of the chapterhead page is empty in print?

Comment: …what? Can you try to elaborate?  I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I want create one  white and empty page after each page header of chapters.

Comment: `\clearpage` should do the trick, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
[\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage]

%\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
‎\chapter{Chapter One}‎
\lipsum[1-2]
‎\end{document}‎
```

[image]

Comment: took the thought straight from my mind :)